# Snowflake SQL - moving variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to do simple thing but still struggling with it.

I have query like this:

```
SELECT
TRUNC(aa.datum::DATE,'mm') AS "Month",
SUM(aa.something) AS count
FROM table1 aa
join table2 bb
ON aa.id = bb.id
WHERE YEAR(aa.datum::DATE) = 2022
and aa.datum::DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-01'::DATE AND  '2022-10-30'::DATE
AND bb.datum_objednani::DATE >= '2022-08-01'::DATE
and aa.something != '' and aa.parameter = 'X'  and bb.datum != ''
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;
```

WHat I need is to create some kind of loop that will move back in time and give me result for every month until start of the year.

SO first run will be with this:

```
and aa.datum::DATE BETWEEN '2022-10-01'::DATE AND  '2022-10-31'::DATE
    AND bb.datum_objednani::DATE >= '2022-08-01'::DATE
```

and next run should be

```
and aa.datum::DATE BETWEEN '2022-09-01'::DATE AND  '2022-09-30'::DATE
    AND bb.datum_objednani::DATE >= '2022-08-01'::DATE
```

until

```
aa.datum::DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01'::DATE AND  '2022-01-31'::DATE
    AND bb.datum_objednani::DATE >= '2021-11-01'::DATE
```

with fact that every month have different number of days.

Anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind solved.

My solution:

```
  SELECT
TRUNC(aa.datum::DATE,'mm') AS "Month",
SUM(aa.something) AS sum
FROM something aa
join something bb
ON aa.id = bb.id
WHERE YEAR(aa.datum::DATE) = 2022
and bb.datum_objednani >= dateadd(month, -2, "Month" )
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```